# Can tex4ht output a 'flat XML' (fodt) OpenDocument file?

Tags: tex4ht, open-office

I'm guessing the answer to this question is no, but no harm asking - `tex4ht`, when outputting `oolatex`, outputs an `.odt` OpenDocument, which is actually a .zip file (which then contains `content.xml`, folders with images, etc).

However, there is this OpenDocument "Flat XML" file, which gets the extension '`.fodt`' in Libre/OpenOffice. This one actually even contains encoded binary data of images, within the `<office:binary-data>` tag! There is a bit on this format in [OpenDocument technical specification - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument_technical_specification#Document_Representation).

So, for double-checking what `tex4ht` outputs in case of `oolatex`, I guess I'd prefer a direct "render" to a Flat XML `.fodt` file - instead of bulding the `.odt` zip, then unzipping it to check its content... But I'm not sure if it's possible at all - I cannot find many references for this Flat XML file format.

Many thanks in advance for any answers,
Cheers!

Comment: there is no such option, and I think it would be hard to do it - you would need to post-process the xml with some script and include all images, maybe herder would be to rewrite the tex4ht's ooffice config files. I think better to go this way  would be to convert odt to fodt (see http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=153292 ). or write script to unzip text content from the odt file

Comment: Many thanks for that, @michal.h21 - I was suspecting that is the case; maybe you can move your comment to an answer so I can accept it? Thanks - cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Michal wrote in his comment, there's no option to create a flat ODT document directly with TeX4ht. However, you don't need additional OO wrapper scripts either but can directly use OpenOffice/LibreOffice as a command-line converter:

```
oowriter --convert-to fodt myfile.odt
```

You only have to ensure that the proper OO XSLT filters are installed, i.e. export format `.fodt` is listed as an option in the SaveAs dialog.

Comment: Many thanks for that, @Martin - good to have it in writing :) Cheers!

Comment: This silently exits doing nothing if any OpenOffice/LibreOffice is running - see [here](http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/1686/how-to-not-connect-to-a-running-instance/?answer=1701#post-id-1701) for workaround.